# Enumerator `Array#each` 's {block} can't always change array values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, block, each, enumerator

Ok maybe this is simple but...
given this:

```
arr = ("a".."z").to_a

arr

=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

..and that I'm trying to change all "arr" values to "bad"

why *isn't* this working ?

```
arr.each { |v| v = "bad" }

arr

=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Answers suggested that "v" is a local variable to the block (a "copy" of the array value) and I fully understand that (and never puzzled me before) but then

.. why it is working if array elements are objects ?

```
class Person
  def initialize
    @age = 0
  end
  attr_accessor :age
end

kid = Person.new
man = Person.new
arr = [kid, man]


arr.each { |p| p.age = 50 }

arr[0]
=> #<Person:0xf98298 @age=50>
```

**isn't here "p" still local to the block here?
but then it really affects the objects, how come ?**

Comment: `v` is a *local variable* that is bound to the *value* that was in the index. It is not a "reference" to the original array slot!

Comment: *Objects are values too!* - Ruby uses [Call By Object (Sharing)](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) which explains the mutation side-effects - it's the *same value/object*! The key importance is a *variable **is not** a value*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll expand upon @pst's comment:

> why isn't this working ?

```
arr.each { |v| v = "bad" }
```

Because `each` iterates through the array and puts each item into the block you've given as a *local* variable `v`, as `v` is not a reference to the array `arr`.

```
new_arr = arr.each { |v| v = "bad" }
```

`each` does not give back an array, for that you would use `map` (see @benjaminbenben's answer). Therefore assigning it does not "work".

```
arr.each { |v| arr[arr.index v] = "bad" }
```

Here you put each item in `arr` into the local variable `v`, but you've *also* referred to the array itself in the block, hence you are able to assign to the array and use the local variable `v` to find an index that corresponds to the contents of `v` (but you may find this wouldn't work as you expect when the items are not all unique).

```
arr.each { |p| p.age = 50 }

kid.age #-> 50
```

Here, again you've filled the local variable `p` with each item/object in `arr`, but then you've accessed each item via a method, so you are able to change that item - **you are not changing the array**. It's different because the reference is to the contents of the local variable, which you've mixed up with being a reference to the array. They are separate things.

---

In response to the comment below:

```
arr[0]
# => #<Person:0xf98298 @age=50>
```

It's all about who's referring to whom when.

Try this:

```
v = Person.new
# => #<Person:0x000001008de248 @age=0>
w = Person.new
# => #<Person:0x000001008d8050 @age=0>
x = v
# => #<Person:0x000001008de248 @age=0>
v = Person.new
# => #<Person:0x00000100877e80 @age=0>
arr = [v,w,x]
# => [#<Person:0x00000100877e80 @age=0>, #<Person:0x000001008d8050 @age=0>, #<Person:0x000001008de248 @age=0>]
```

`v` referred to 2 different objects there. `v` is not a fixed thing, it's a name. At first it refers to `#<Person:0x000001008de248 @age=0>`, then it refers to `#<Person:0x00000100877e80 @age=0>`.

Now try this:

```
arr.each { |v| v = "bad" }
# => [#<Person:0x00000100877e80 @age=0>, #<Person:0x000001008d8050 @age=0>, #<Person:0x000001008de248 @age=0>]
```

They are all objects but nothing was updated or "worked". Why? Because when the block is first entered, `v` refers to the item in the array that was yielded (given). So on first iteration `v` is `#<Person:0x00000100877e80 @age=0>`.

But, we then assign `"bad"` to `v`. We are not assigning `"bad"` to the first index of the array *because we aren't referencing the array at all*. `arr` is the reference to the array. Put `arr` inside the block and you can alter it:

```
arr.each { |v| 
  arr[0] = "bad" # yes, a bad idea!
}
```

Why then does `arr.each { |p| p.age = 50 }` update the items in the array? Because `p` refers to the objects that also happen to be in the array. On first iteration `p` refers to the object also known as `kid`, and `kid` has an `age=` method and you stick `50` in it. `kid` is also the first item in the array, but you're talking about `kid` not the array. You could do this:

```
arr.each { |p| p = "bad"; p.age }
NoMethodError: undefined method `age' for "bad":String
```

At first, `p` referred to the object that also happened to be in the array (that's where it was yielded from), but then `p` was made to refer to `"bad"`.

`each` iterates over the array and yields a value on each iteration. You only get the value *not* the array. If you want to update an array you either do:

```
new_arr = arr.map{|v| v = "bad" }
new_arr = arr.map{|v| "bad" } # same thing
```

or

```
arr.map!{|v| v = "bad"}
arr.map!{|v| "bad"}  # same thing
```

as `map` returns an array *filled with the return value of the block*. `map!` will update the reference you called it on with an array *filled with the return value of the block*. Generally, it's a bad idea to update an object when iterating over it anyway. I find it's always better to think of it as creating a new array, and then you can use the `!` methods as a shortcut.

Comment: i had mistyped my "test query": kid.age #=> 50 It was instead arr[0] # => #<Person:0xf98298 @age=50> . So doesn't this show that the actual array contains a changed value ?

Comment: @lain i edited the question with the changes so you can read it better if you wish, thanks

Comment: @lain thanks now it's all clear, thanks for the time you've spent on this! :) I really needed a thorough explaination! Voting best answer here, and hoping other people would benefit from your answer! Well done man!

Answer (score 4):

In example

```
arr.each { |v| v = "bad" }
```

"v" is just reference to string, when you do `v = "bad"`, you reassign local variable. To make everything bad you can do like that:

```
arr.each { |v| v.replace "bad" }
```

Next time you can play with `Object#object_id`

```
puts arr[0].object_id #will be save as object_id in first iteration bellow
arr.each { |v| puts v.object_id }
```

Comment: nice, i didn't know .replace method :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for .map - which returns a new array with the the return value of the block for each element.

```
arr.map { "bad" }

=> ["bad", "bad", "bad", "bad", …]
```

using `.map!` will alter the contents of the original array rather than return a new one.

Comment: thanks I will probably follow this way, but still I am questioning myself why my first solution does work in a case and does not in another (check my edit) thanks

Comment: ah! @Iain's answer seems to cover that pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
arry = Array.new(arry.length,"bad")
```

This will set the a default value of "bad" to the **arry.length**

Comment: what the..! I can believe I missed this! It's the easiest, more convenient and elegant way to solve the problem I was trying to solve in the first time ! Thanks! Next time i'll spend more time reading on core classes .new method! Upvoting!

Comment: p.s.: if you use parentesys for Array.new(parameter) remember they must come after .new without spaces! -> Class.new(parameter). If you have a space between .new and (parameter) you will get syntax error. Just thought it could be useful to remind it (to myself for first) :